# How do I detect whether the file system is case-sensitive?

Tags: java, filesystems, case-sensitive, system-properties

I have a `List<String>` of file names from a folder and a certain file name as `String`. I want to detect whether the file name is in the list, but need to respect the underlying file system's property of whether it is case-sensitive.

Is there any easy way to do this (other than the "hack" of checking `System.getProperty("os.name", "").toLowerCase().indexOf("windows")!=-1`)? ;-)

Comment: Note that "case insensitive filesystem" is not equivalent to "OS is Windows", anyway.  All of Windows, Linux and Mac OS can use either case-sensitive or case-insensitive filesystems; don't confuse the concepts.  The "hack" would be to assert that a lowercase filename doesn't exist; create a (temporary) file with that name in uppercase, then check if the lowercase-named file exists.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't use Strings to represent your files; use java.io.File:

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

Comment: As an additional note, you can get an array of files from a directory using File's listFiles() method on a File object for said directory.  This can then be manipulated as an array or converted to a list using Arrays.asList

Comment: I don't think this answer works in the OS X case. OS X appears to use a UnixFileSystem as its FileSystem implementation regardless of whether the File is on a case sensitive or insensitive HFS+ filesystem. Therefore, File.equals(File) will return false on a case insensitive file system when filenames with differing cases are passed. Edit: just noticed @SaM said the same thing in another answer.

Comment: In the end I found a convoluted way of using File.exists (which *does* seem to obey the filesystem's case rules) was the only way.

Answer (score 3):

```
boolean isFileSystemCaseSensitive = !new File( "a" ).equals( new File( "A" ) );
```

Comment: Have just tested this on Mac OSX, default case insensitive file system and it doesn't return the expected result.

Comment: With the note that it doesn't take the file system in account, just the OS - this answer is no worse than accepted one. As long as you are aware of it's fine. I'll take it as I couldn't find better solution that takes FS in account. +1

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can use the [`IOCase`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOCase.html).

Comment: Again - doesn't work for OS X very well. Just assumes case sensitive, because the file separators are forward slashes! See this discussion between the devs for more: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IO-171

Answer (score 1):

Write a file named "HelloWorld"; attempt to read a file named "hELLOwORLD"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any of the existing examples actually handle this properly, you need to write the file to disk.

```
    private boolean caseSensitivityCheck() {
    try {
        File currentWorkingDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        File case1 = new File(currentWorkingDir, "case1");
        File case2 = new File(currentWorkingDir, "Case1");
        case1.createNewFile();
        if (case2.createNewFile()) {
            System.out.println("caseSensitivityCheck: FileSystem of working directory is case sensitive");
            case1.delete();
            case2.delete();
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("caseSensitivityCheck: FileSystem of working directory is NOT case sensitive");
            case1.delete();
            return false;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following static method:

```
/**
 * <p>
 * Checks, whether the provided path points to a case-sensitive file system or not.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * It does so by creating two temp-files in the provided  path and comparing them. Note that you need to have write
 * access to the provided path.
 *
 * @param pathToFileSystem path to the file system to test
 * @param tmpFileName      name of the temp file that is created
 * @return {@code true}, if the provided path points to a case-sensitive file system; {@code false} otherwise
 * @throws IOException if IO operation fails
 */
public static boolean fileSystemIsCaseSensitive(Path pathToFileSystem, String tmpFileName) throws IOException {

    Path a = Files.createFile(pathToFileSystem.resolve(Paths.get(tmpFileName.toLowerCase())));
    Path b = null;
    try {
        b = Files.createFile(pathToFileSystem.resolve(Paths.get(tmpFileName.toUpperCase())));
    } catch (FileAlreadyExistsException e) {
        return false;
    } finally {
        Files.deleteIfExists(a);
        if (b != null) Files.deleteIfExists(b);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Use it as follows:

```
@Test
void fileSystemIsCaseSensitive01() throws IOException {
    assertTrue(Util.fileSystemIsCaseSensitive(Paths.get("/Volumes/Case-sensitive-Volume/Data"), "a"));
}

@Test
void fileSystemIsCaseSensitive02() throws IOException {
    assertFalse(Util.fileSystemIsCaseSensitive(Paths.get("/Volumes/Case-insensitive-Volume/Data"), "a"));
}
```

Note the different volumes provided (Case-sensitive-Volume vs. Case-**in**sensitve-Volume).